# Parameters<> utility type cannot infer types when using generic type as index

Tags: typescript

Consider [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gDgFwJYHsQGcoG8CwAoKQqNYAGnyKgQHcVyCiEALAJ2GHwF998BjNdAigATJL2RoAhiwCeUALzYKRANrwJGAHQkAugC4oACkkHBLJCADmpKACMDtlCgA2wSSACUCgHzYo-DBdgTWcUS0MsKBMom3s7KE4vTnpKNURULRoUfSNeA3AIW2AWL3lfSID0IJCww14klNV1DPRNZjZgHMNS8oT6TijMSoQePAQZOGAoAAUAHgAVKGAADwRQYUxmgV9FaelJCGA1lnRZ8cmUADMRMQ1pGRV5nW98c6mYECnd2a2tEhe8PhLmAQOIMv4UBA4M4xJI1sIFktVutNultoYUGiQAZ5jZNPjpJZ0AY9iwDkdiqc3lcbmCpLJHs8vLgGIRhlBLiAFLS7gzMRodMpCG94opqddRHSQPdGUKOSBDPjNIT0F4APRqqDzJhITDFFgoFhQdBMFDUTCXQ1aibAdC8cyIOxgIQsEEgCyWKCWJAAN1tUBAKCWLANJ00XFG-ChMN4cOAwkMv1aJHVmu1uqoNv8TGAvAA1lBaCw8%20g%20JDobD4YmscnPjYAOSSes2BCu4AeMvRyvx6saVpZGwARg8QA), also below:

```
enum Options {
    one,
    two,
    three
}

const dictionary = {
    [Options.one]: (a: string, b: boolean) => { console.log({ a: a, b: b }) },
    [Options.two]: (c: number) => { console.log(c) },
    [Options.three]: () => { },
} as const

function complicated<T extends Options>(option: T, ...args: Parameters<typeof dictionary[T]>) {
    const fn = dictionary[option]
    type b = typeof dictionary[T]
    fn(...args) // This error shows for Typescript but running gives no errors.
}
```

When creating a type statically like `type One = Parameters<typeof dictionary[Options.one]>`, the type is correct, as `[a: string, b: boolean]`.

But using the generic parameter above with `Parameters<typeof dictionary[T]>`, the `fn` variable shows it is a `(arg0: never, b: boolean) => void`. Calling `fn(...arg)` is type checked to have error, when executing the script works fine.

Why is this and what should be done to eliminate the error?

**Edit**: This is currently an open issue on Github [#49802](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49802), also referred to in #49700